# Can't load libOpenSLES.so when I run a android ndk application on emulator

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to compile and run vlc android app on emulator on ubuntu 11.04.

I get it compiles and linked. But when I run the app on emulator, I get the following 'usr/lib/libOpenSLES.so not found' error.

I have checked that I do have libOpenSLES.so in the right path on my ubuntu environment. So why it said it can't find it?

`E/LibVLC  (  443): Can't load vlcjni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1962]:    33 could not load needed library '/home/michael/Programs/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib/libOpenSLES.so' for 'libvlcjni.so' (load_library[1104]: Library '/home/michael/Programs/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib/libOpenSLES.so' not found)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like the app has been linked with a full path to libOpenSLES on your development machine. When you run on the emulator you want it to resolve the OpenSLES lib to the correct place on the emulator, not your dev machine.

The toolchain should already be set up to resolve the correct library paths, you should be able to link with just "-lOpenSLES" which will resolve to your NDK dir at build time and the correct location on the emulator / device at runtime.